# mysql insert SELECT syntax error fix

Tags: mysql

```
    INSERT INTO `yr8tu_posts` NULL,"1538",Replace(meta_value,".jpg",""),"","publish","open","open",,Replace(meta_value,".jpg",""),post_id,"","0","attachment","image/jpeg","0")
SELECT meta_value, post_id FROM `yr8tu_postmeta` WHERE meta_key = "_wp_attached_file";
```

Above is the query I use for an INSERT SELECT statement, but it keeps giving the syntax error. I tried going through the mysql documentation also for possible ideas about the error, but couldn't locate it.

Comment: Missing Clause ***VALUES***

Comment: INSERT INTO my_table (x,y,z) SELECT x,y,REPLACE(z,'a') FROM ...

Comment: Hard to tell what you are trying to do. What is it you're trying?

Comment: @ Hanky i had values earlier, but if you the syntax for insert select, it says values to be removed.. check thiss [link]dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html   @juergend im trying to insert a new value in the table yr8tu_posts, but 2 of the values are to be picked from columns from another table postmeta..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this...

```
INSERT INTO `yr8tu_posts` 
SELECT NULL
     , "1538"
     , REPLACE(meta_value,".jpg","")
     , ""
     , "publish"
     , "open"
     , "open"
     , ""
     , REPLACE(meta_value,".jpg","")
     , post_id
     , ""
     , "0"
     , "attachment"
     , "image/jpeg"
     , "0"
     , meta_value
     , post_id 
  FROM `yr8tu_postmeta` 
 WHERE meta_key = "_wp_attached_file";
```

Comment: @ Strawberry OK, i used this, but doesnt seem to work.. [code]INSERT INTO `yr8tu_posts` SELECT  NULL,"1538",NOW(),NOW(),"",Replace(meta_value,".jpg",""),"","publish","open","open","",Replace(meta_value,".jpg",""),"","",NOW(),NOW(),"",post_id,"","0","attachment","image/jpeg","0" FROM `yr8tu_postmeta` WHERE meta_key = "_wp_attached_file";

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" is not a standard error message.

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Replace(meta_value,".jpg",""),"","",now(),now(),"",post_id,"","0","attachment","' at line 1

Comment: ok yes, worked for me.. but "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). " now just to clarify the metavalue, post_id, meta_key columns are in the postmeta table..(and >3000 values WHERE meta_key = "_wp_attached_file") So what could be the reason?

Comment: You mean `SELECT * FROM yr8tu_posts` returns an empty result?

Comment: You know this would be a lot simpler if you just provided proper DDLs

Comment: actually the tables are complicated so couldnt create a fiddle also to demonstrate..

Comment: Er, no. postmeta has three columns that we're interested in, and posts has 17. That's simple, not complicated. Anyway, the original question is resolved, so I suggest we mark this as answered.